# Mostrar elementos de una lista enlazada con manytomanyfield

Tags: html, django

Este es mi archivo models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Jugadores(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    edad = models.IntegerField()    
    posicion = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Equipo(models.Model):
    pos = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    puntos = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    jugadores = models.ManyToManyField(Jugadores)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Mi duda es que quiero mostrar en mi template llamada jugadores.html, la lista de jugadores enlazada a cada equipo. Es decir si mi equipo se llama Barcelona, que al pulsar sobre el enlace a Barcelona, me aparezcan la lista de jugadores del Barcelona. Y es que me aparecen la lista de todos los jugadores introducidos en mi base de datos.

Este es mi archivo views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader ,context
from .models import Equipo, Jugadores

def inicio(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def ver_equipo(request):
    equipo = Equipo.objects.all()
    context = {'equipos': equipo}
    return render(request, 'equipos.html', context)

def ver_clasificacion(request):
    clasificacion = Equipo.objects.order_by('puntos')
    context = {'clasificaciones': clasificacion}
    return render(request, 'clasificacion.html', context)

def ver_jugadores(request):
    jugador = Jugadores.objects.all()
    context = {'jugadores': jugador }
    return render(request, 'jugadores.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno lo que usualmente se hace, es que dada tu lista de Equipos en tu vista de `ver_equipo` en el template lo que haces es recorrer todos los equipos, de esa forma, añadir un link hacia una nueva vista, un ejemplo seria así.

```
<table>
{% for equipo in equipos %}
<tr>
    <th>{{ equipo|upper }}</th>
    <td><a href="{% url "ver_jugadores_equipo" equipo.id %}">Ver equipo</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Luego en tus views.py agregas una nueva vista:

```
...
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
def ver_jugadores_equipo(request, pk):
    equipo = get_object_or_404(Equipo, pk=pk)
    jugadores = equipo.jugadores.all()
    return render(request, 'lista_jugadores_por_equipo.html', {'jugadores': jugadores})
...
```

Luego en tus urls.py

```
...
# agregas dentro de tu arreglo de urlpatterns
url(r'jugadores/equipo/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.ver_jugadores_equipo, name='ver_jugadores_equipo'),
...
```

Y solo queda que crees el template de 'lista_jugadores_por_equipo.html' que viene con los jugadores de el equipo al que le diste click en el link. Y debes recorrer y empezar a listar

Cualquier duda, comenta.